# need help with the phrase "account for"

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality

I am confused about how **"accounting for"** is used.
Here is my sentence:

> "As needed, we compute few performance metrics to the proposed
> approach accounting for quantifying its performance."

Is this sentence correct both grammatically and in meaning?

Comment: Unless one has some knowledge in the field, your context is difficult to understand. You might consider simplifying it.

Comment: Agree with @fev and also, I suspect you can replace "accounting for quantifying" with the simpler "to quantify".

Comment: To paraphrase what you are saying , "we calculate performance metrics [to measure the performance]".Do you really need to say the portion in brackets?  And what does "As needed" mean? Who needs it and why? Note also that "a few* means several, but *few" means "not very many".

Comment: yes the portion in brackets. as needed==it requires ( something like that). few== yes less than 7 metrics